# Error - I cannot using phone register through Android studio&FireBase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can someone give me a code that Illustrates how to make phone number registration through firebase? I tried to do that, but something went wrong  with the code, already in the beginning of it. Screenshot of the error is attached to this post. Please help me figure out how can I solve this(or give me an example of the code).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiFD3.png)

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of text in your question. Instead show the actual code as text. That ensures that Stack Overflow can highlight the code, it becomes searchable, and we can copy/paste snippets of it in our answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to  import the Gradle Files correctly. Also, Check for the Package Name and the Gradle dependencies used in the original project.

Connect Firebase to your Android Project as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase.html)

Check out the docs for the sample on Phone Authentication through Firebase.

[Link to the Docs](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/PhoneAuthActivity.java)

Comment: First of all you need to connect to Firebase. A simple Google or link mentioned in the answer will help you.
Next go to the sample where the code is shown of Phone Authentication.
Check this sample 
 https://github.com/androidmads/FirebasePhoneAuthSample/tree/master/app/src/main